# Referencing Methods and repositories from within sub viewModel in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Still feeling my way through MVVM, and have come up against this issue:

I have a top level ViewModel, lets call it ModelLevel1.

I have a sub ViewModel that belongs to it, that a control uses for all its bindings, lets call that ControlViewModel1. The Control only binds to ControlViewModel1.

In the Top level Viewmodel, there is a Repository, and a method to get a record from the repository from an id.

What is the best way to allow ControlViewModel1 to access the method so it can get a record from the repository?

Cheers,

Rob

Comment: Use a publish and subscribe of the `EventAggregator` .Ref  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355473/Prism-EventAggregator-Sample

Comment: @user2526236: I don't think using the EventAggregator makes sense in this scenario. It looks more a way to increase the article possition in google ...

Comment: Inversion of Control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSingle_responsibility_principle&ei=DelIVczhHI32aM6-gOgH&usg=AFQjCNFoci3JyHtoEwOx1lduCbF7IcS50Q&sig2=de7QInzlRRbHV5bVmraDOw&bvm=bv.92291466,d.bGg) extract the logic of getting the record to a class that knows how to do it and inject that dependency to both ViewModels.

This approach can be reused by other classes, can be easily tested and is performant (unlike the aggregated events proposal).

Comment: This forced me to look into dependency injection, and its actually not as bad as I though - quite a tidy way to do things...

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to allow ControlViewModel1 to access the method so it can get a record from the repository?

IMHO Controls are self contained units which have dependency properties which serve the function of a VM; hence no VM is needed.

1. Create a Dependency property on the control which takes in the target VM and hence has access to the method.
2. Create a static property on the app which will contain the VM in question and access it as a static call.

MVVM is simply a separation of concerns, remember Xaml ultimately gets `compiled` into C# code which is executed along side the code. Whatever process you use in code to access methods and objects can also be carried over to control instances on the page.